# Linux, компиляция драйвера

Tags: linux, компиляция, драйвер

Пытаюсь установить драйвер, получаю ошибки на скриншоте.

```
root@kali:~/Downloads/wires-`driver/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047# make`                                                              
/bin/sh: 1: bc: not found
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.4.0-kali3-amd64/build M=/root/Downloads/wires-driver/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047  modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/5.4.0-kali3-amd64/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [Makefile:1828: modules] Error 2
```

[image: Скрин]

Comment: приведите текст ошибок текстом

Comment: Отредактировал, добавил в тексте

Answer (score 3):

Суть ошибки

```
/bin/sh: 1: bc: not found
```

Установите bc

```
sudo apt install bc
```

При работе под рутом иногда получается кривая переменная PATH, выполните ещё

```
. /etc/profile
```

По следующей ошибке

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-amd64 # linux-headers-5.4.0-*-amd64
```

Обнови  `linux-image-amd64` чтоб версия ядра и хидеров совпадали.

Возможно ещё понадобятся пакеты

```
build-essential kmod flex cpio libncurses5-dev
```

Comment: Установил, ошибка bc: not found пропала, следующая осталась

Comment: должна бы исправиться. попробуй профайл активировать

Comment: . /etc/profile выполнил, не помогло:

/lib/modules/5.4.0-kali3-amd64/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.

Comment: вот видишь - другая ошибка теперь)

Comment: Одной меньше) что дальше?

Comment: уже исправил ответ

Comment: Это норм? 
'Reading package lists... Done'
'Building dependency tree'       
'Reading state information... Done'
'E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-5.4.0-kali3-amd64'
'E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-5.4.0-kali3-amd64''
'E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-5.4.0-kali3-amd64''

Comment: ну значит пакет немного не так называется в кали. попробуй просто `linux-headers-amd64` должен поставить актуальную версию

Comment: Второй пакет тоже установил, проблема сохранилась

Comment: значит версия ядра не та. поставь хидеры и имэдж одной версии.

Comment: linux-headers-amd64 поставил успешно, проблема сохранилась

Comment: Не понимаю, о чем Вы? Как чекнуть их версию? как поставить одной версии?